# e.target.closest() returns null in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a div with a className of `styles.likesTotal` (using css modules) that has a click event listener on it. Within this div there's a button with a click event listener as well. When I click the button, the event bubbles up and triggers the parent div's event listener, which I would like to stop from happening.

Initially, I used `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the bubbling effect and it worked just fine, but then I came across this article which said one should never use `stopPropagation()`

https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

So I decided to go the route of using `e.target.closest()`, but it keeps returning null, even though the selector is definitely valid. The thing is, closest works if I try to target the '.App' className, but it just won't work within my component. If someone could offer some insight, I'd really appreciate it.

Code:

```
export const Suggestion = ({ request, sortType, sort }) => {
  const dispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);
  const titleRef = useRef();
  const storageSortVal = sessionStorage.getItem('sortType');
  const handleLikesMouseEnter = (e) => addLikesHoverBgColor(e, styles);
  const handleLikeMouseLeave = (e) => removeLikesHoverBgColor(e, styles);
  const handleSuggestionMouseOver = () => addHoverColor(titleRef, styles);
  const handleSuggestionMouseLeave = () => removeHoverColor(titleRef, styles);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.closest(styles.likesTotal)); // null
    console.log(e.target.closest('.likesTotal')); // null

    sessionStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', JSON.stringify(window.scrollY));
  };

  const handleLikesClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // e.stopPropagation();
    dispatch({
      type: sort === 'upvote-sort' ? 'upvote-sort' : 'upvote',
      requestID: request.requestID,
      sortType: storageSortVal || 'most upvotes',
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={styles.container}
        onMouseOver={handleSuggestionMouseOver}
        onMouseLeave={handleSuggestionMouseLeave}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <Link to={`/feedback-detail/${request.requestID}`}>
          <div className={styles.innerContainer}>
            <div className={styles.textBox}>
              <span className={styles.title} ref={titleRef}>
                {request.title}
              </span>
              <p className={styles.description} lang="en">
                {request.description}
              </p>
              <span className={styles.category}>{request.category}</span>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.likesBox}>

              {/* span element I'm trying to target */}
              <span
                className={`${styles.likesTotal} ${
                  request.upvoted && styles.active
                }`}
                onClick={handleLikesClick}
                onMouseEnter={handleLikesMouseEnter}
                onMouseLeave={handleLikeMouseLeave}
                tabIndex="0"
              >
                <img
                  className={styles.likeArrow}
                  src={request.upvoted ? arrowUpWhite : arrowUp}
                  alt="arrow up"
                />
                {request.upvotes}
              </span>

              <div className={styles.commentBox}>
                <img
                  className={`${styles.commentBubble} ${
                    request.comments.length > 9 && styles.customPositionRight
                  }`}
                  src={comment}
                  alt="comment bubble"
                />
                <span className={styles.commentsTotal}>
                  {request.comments ? request.comments.length : 0}
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

styles:

```
.likesTotal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: $lightGrey;
  font-family: $robotoBold;
  color: $darkNavy;
  padding: 0.7rem 1.3rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;

  @include desktopXL {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: From where the styles are coming I believe you are using module css, coz if you are using the module css then class is going to be different then `likeArrow` you should give a try by putting a static class and then reference it in `e.target.closest('.static-class')`

Comment: Hi, Ali. I've already given it a try by passing in a string rather than using the css modules format for the value of the selector, but it still returns a value of null. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Hi, @Nunchuk check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget

Comment: If you can create a codesandbox maybe I can debug and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Try [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.`

I mean something like

```
e.target?.closest()
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I gave it a shot with optional chaining, but I'm still getting the same result. But I wasn't aware of this feature, and it seems it could be useful in the future, so thank you.